# Disable microphone when recording a video

Tags: android, video-recording

I try to:

```
audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
```

and it doesn't help!! (please help to find a solution)

Comment: We're going to need more information such as the API version, targeted phone, your manifest and the activity/fragment that this code is used in

Comment: Api 11 , i need all phones, i try it in activity,                                                                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

Comment: I find The answer!!Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include what you did?

Comment: i add answer at the bottom )) upvote if agree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mrec = new MediaRecorder();  
mCamera.unlock();

mrec.setCamera(mCamera);

mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);

mrec.setOutputFormat(profile.fileFormat);
mrec.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);
mrec.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
mrec.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
mrec.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);
mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
mrec.setOutputFile("/sdcard/sample.3gp");

mrec.prepare();
mrec.start();
```